# Calculating length between 3D points

Tags: python, numpy, distance, spline, abaqus

I created a spline in Abaqus and now I would like to calculate the length of that spline.
The spline consists of 19 points `[CoGX_Init, CoGY_Init, CoGZ_Init]`.
I want to determine the distance between each point with the following formula; `(sqrt((x2-x1)**2+(y2-y1)**2+(z2-z1)**2))` and then count these points to find the complete length of the spline.

This is my code;

```
N = np.zeros((1, len(CoGZ_Init)))
for j in range(0, len(CoGZ_Init)-1):
    x1 = CoGX_Init[j]
    x2 = CoGX_Init[j+1]
    y1 = CoGY_Init[j]
    y2 = CoGY_Init[j+1]
    z1 = CoGZ_Init[j]
    z2 = CoGZ_Init[j+1]
    N[j] = sqrt((x2-x1)**2+(y2-y1)**2+(z2-z1)**2)

print(sum[N])
```

When I run this, I receive the error the following error for line `N[j]`:
`index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Your array `N` is an array like `[[0., 0., 0., ... 0.]]` -- so you need to change

```py
N = np.zeros((1, len(CoGZ_Init)))
```

to

```
N = np.zeros(len(CoGZ_Init))
```

**OR** change

```py
N[j] = sqrt((x2-x1)**2+(y2-y1)**2+(z2-z1)**2)
```

to

```py
N[0][j] = sqrt((x2-x1)**2+(y2-y1)**2+(z2-z1)**2)
```

Comment: Ofcourse!! Thank you!